# I need to user an enumerations to represent difficulties levels. I keep getting an error about using cin>>

Tags: c++, enumeration

I have to use a enumerations to represent the difficulty levels. Here is the code.

```
// Menu Chooser
// Demonstrates the switch statement

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main() 
    {
        cout << "Difficulty Levels\n\n";
        cout << "1 - Easy\n";
        cout << "2 - Normal\n";
        cout << "3 - Hard\n\n";

        enum userChoice {Easy, Normal, Hard};
        userChoice choice;
        cout << "Choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1: 
                cout << "You picked Easy.\n";
                break;
        case 2: 
                cout << "You picked Normal.\n";
                break;
        case 3: 
                cout << "You picked Hard.\n";
                break;
        default:
                cout << "You made an illegal choice.\n";
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

and the error message:

> error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Unless you have written a stream operator that can read from an istream into a userChoice enum, the error message is correct.

Comment: You are not using the names `Easy`, `Normal` and `Hard` anywhere in your code - why have you defined the enum at all? Just make `choice` an `int`.

Comment: Choice was originally an int, that's the thing. It's a homework assignment and an enum has to be used. I've tried everything and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading user input, it is not safe to expect they will enter a correct value. However, this seems extreme for your assignment.

My first thought is to just read in an int, then cast it to the enum.

```
int input;
cin >> input;

userChoice choice = (userChoice)input;
```

This should work, however I haven't tested it.

Comment: Yes it does seem a bit much being as we haven't went into casting or anything. I think the directions may just be a little vague, but on that note this is definitely my best solution. Thank you!

Comment: Enums are very powerful and useful, however it can be a little funky learning them. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There is no default implementation of the `>>` operator for taking an input and mapping it to an `enum`. You will need to take in an `int` as an input and then map it to the `enum`. Alternatively, you could write an overload for the `>>` operator that maps the input to your enum.

Of course, looking at your code, you don't seem to be using the defined enum for anything. Perhaps you could remove it and use an int instead?

Comment: I have to use an enum its for a homework assignment, it was an int originally. I feel like the assignment may be lacking in some direction, because I'm not to the point in c++ of even really knowing what you mean by the overload, or how to map the input to the enum.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the enums chapter in your textbook, or searching the internet for articles that help get a better understanding of the concept. For example, here is an article that talks about enums and their relationship with an int : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your `enum` values into your `cases`:

```
switch (choice)
{
case Easy: 
        cout << "You picked Easy.\n";
        break;
case Normal: 
        cout << "You picked Normal.\n";
        break;
case Hard: 
        cout << "You picked Hard.\n";
        break;
default:
        cout << "You made an illegal choice.\n";
}
```

To convert from text to `enum` type, I suggest you use a table (your instructor probably hasn't covered the topic of `std::map` which would be the preferred method).

```
struct Enum_Entry
{
  UserChoice value;
  const char * text;
};

static const Enum_Entry lookup_table[] =
{
  {Easy, "easy"},
  {Normal, "normal"},
  {Hard, "hard"},
};
static const unsigned int items_in_table =
  sizeof(lookup_table) / sizeof(lookup_table[0]);

std::string selection_text;

// Input enum as text
std::cin >> selection_text;

// Convert to lower case to make comparison easier
std::transform(selection_text.begin(),  // Start of range
               selection_text.end(),    // End of range
               selection.begin(),       // Destination for transformation.
               std::tolower);           // Transformation function.

//  Lookup the text into the table and retrieve the enum value.
UserChoice choice = Easy;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < items_in_table; ++i)
{
  if (selection_text == lookup_table[i].text)  
  {  
    choice = lookup_table[i].value;  
    break;
```

`}`
`}`

Another method is to use an `if-else-if` ladder:

```
  choice = easy;
  if (selection_text == "easy")
  {
     choice = Easy;
  }
  else if (selection_text == "hard")
  {
    choice = Hard;
  }
  else if (selection_text == "normal")
  {
    choice = Normal;
  }
  else
  {
    choice = Easy;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even think about changing my case names, good catch. And the other info provided will definitely be valuable in the future, so thanks again.

Comment: If you find my answer useful, click on the check mark.